# How to reduce the duplicate code in logback-spring.xml file in many different project?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

#### description:

- My company have a lot of `spring` project with using basically the same (90% the same)  `logback-spring.xml` in all project, such as `scanPeriod` and `LOG_PATTERN` are different. So my boss ask me to reduce duplicate code in `logback-spring.xml` file.
- All project rarely change the `logback-spring.xml` file, but they may change it in the future.
- If I need post the `logback-spring.xml` code, I'll remove company information in it and post it later.

#### what I have tried:

1. Use `maven` to share `logback-spring.xml`. But the `logback-spring.xml` are **basically** the same, not exactly the same.
2. All projects have a dependency to a company basic library named `framework`, so I can store all `logback-spring.xml` in `framework`. But it didn't reduce any duplicate code.
3. (here now)Tell my boss there is no need to reduce the duplicate code in a config file, such as `logback-spring.xml`. Because they are technically not **code**, they can't build or run.

#### example file:

- The "xxx" and "xxxx" part are changed depends on project.
- Some project may add or remove some `springProperty`
- `springProperty` name maybe different.
- `maxFileSize` maybe different.
- `scanPeriod` and `LOG_PATTERN` maybe different.
- etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
    <springProperty scope="context" name="springAppName"  source="spring.application.name" defaultValue="cloud1-service"/>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="emailSmtpHost" source="xxx.admin.email.smtpHost"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="emailSmtpPort" source="xxx.admin.email.smtpPort"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="emailUsername" source="xxx.admin.email.username"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="emailPassword" source="xxx.admin.email.password"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="emailTitle" source="xxx.admin.email.title"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="emailFrom" source="xxx.admin.email.from"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="emailTo" source="xxx.admin.email.to"/>

    <property name="LOG_CONTEXT_NAME" value="${springAppName}"/>
    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="logs/"/>
    <property name="LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [TraceId=%yellow(%X{traceId}),SpanId=%green(%X{spanId}),ParentSpanId=%blue(%X{parentId})]
                [%thread] %-5level %logger{10}-%msg%n"/>

    <appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <smtpHost>${emailSmtpHost}</smtpHost>
        <smtpPort>${emailSmtpPort}</smtpPort>
        <username>${emailUsername}</username>
        <password>${emailPassword}</password>
        <to>${emailTo},${emailCopy}</to>
        <from>${emailFrom}</from>
        <subject>${emailTitle}(${springAppName})</subject>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
        <SSL>true</SSL>
        <asynchronousSending>true</asynchronousSending>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ERROR_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOG_HOME}/${HOSTNAME}-${LOG_CONTEXT_NAME}.error.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/biz/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>365</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>128 MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </layout>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="BIZ_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOG_HOME}/${HOSTNAME}-${LOG_CONTEXT_NAME}.biz.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/biz/${HOSTNAME}-${LOG_CONTEXT_NAME}.biz-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>365</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>128 MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC_ERROR_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
        <queueSize>512</queueSize>
        <appender-ref ref="ERROR_FILE"/>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC_BIZ_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
        <queueSize>512</queueSize>
        <appender-ref ref="BIZ_FILE"/>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC_STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
        <queueSize>512</queueSize>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </appender>

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_BIZ_FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_ERROR_FILE"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="com.xxxx.cloud1" level="debug" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_BIZ_FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_ERROR_FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="EMAIL"/>
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

#### question

1. Any way to reduce the duplicate code in `logback-spring.xml` file in many different project?
2. Do we really need to reduce the duplicate code in a config file, such as `logback-spring.xml`?

Comment: Do you really need the `logback-spring.xml` at all? `scanPeriod` doesn't really make sense for an xml that is being shipped as part of the application (as you cannot open the jar edit the file, close it so that it will be re-read). The `LOG_PATTERN` can be set through `application.properties`.

Comment: @M. Deinum they have more different part than I mention, I just name a few as an example. such as logger name are different, I'll edit to add them.

Comment: logger names for what? Can you show such a `logback-spring.xml`? If the logger names are for specifiying at which level that can also be done through `application.properties`.

Comment: I guess, you could generate logback-spring.xml on fly from a template when application compiles. This could be a maven plugin. Take openapi-generator-maven-plugin as example.

Comment: @M. Deinum sry I'm too busy yesterday, I add an example file to the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logback allows you to include other configuration files within your main `logback.xml` using the `<include>` element. You can create a common configuration file with shared settings and include it in each project's logback configuration file

**common logback**

```
<configuration>
  <!-- Shared conf here -->
<configuration>
```

**specific logback**

```
<configuration>
  <include resource="common-logback.xml" />
  <!-- Specific conf here -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: good idea, +1 for your effort,I want to see more answer so I'll keep the question for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method you can reference.

Try to abstract these different log.xml files to JAVA objects and persist this data.

When start the application, you just need to convert these to Xml files. It'

more flexible and easier to manage JAVA objects than manage Xml static files.

Comment: good idea. I want to see more answer so I'll keep the question for a few days.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).